# Incorrect tooltip on "new" Tag Info tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, new-answers

The title of [the "new" Tag Info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/new) reads:

> New answers by new users tagged c++

The tooltip over the "new" tab itself reads:

> New questions by new users of this tag

"questions" should be "answers."

Comment: thanks for reporting this, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-completed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-completed/new)